# Simplecdn alternatives for progressive streaming

Tags: streaming, cdn

I´m looking for a CDN to host my videos, but I need the ability to progressively stream from them (currently not available at simplecdn).

Comment: How much data are you looking to push per month? And how much space do your videos occupy?

Answer (score 1):

[BitGravity](http://www.bitgravity.com) supports progressive streaming (I *hate* the term pseudo-streaming!) for both FLVs and MP4s.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.aiso.net and their CDN product, I'm pretty sure they support that (pseudostreaming).

Answer (score 0):

SimpleCDN used to support pseudo streaming but then for some reason stopped.  [MaxCDN](http://www.maxcdn.com) supports pseudo streaming.  Here is their [demo](http://www.maxcdn.com/flowplayer_pseudo_streaming.php), using FlowPlayer.  Good luck!